# Progressing Gantt chart

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to make a Gantt chart for a process scheduling simulator, and I've found some libs like plotly.
But instead of plotting the whole chart already done, I need to see it progressing, like a loading bar for every process.

Anyone with a idea of a lib or something that could be useful to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: So you want to animate your plot by like month or duration or something? Or you want to be able to take snapshots at different times? I have no idea what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Oh, imagine every bar like a loading screen. I need to see them progressing. The chart starts without anything and is getting built, something like, the first bar takes 3 seconds complete, then the second one starts and takes like 5 seconds, and so on. Like the bottom part of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ikcIKDGEz4